# HoughLinesP not detecting expected lines

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying out OpenCV to do some image processing. Admittedly I'm a noob at this stuff, but I feel like I'm wrapping my brain around it somewhat. I'm using a mask to detect the lighter areas of the image, then running a canny detector and finally a HoughLinesP detection. Code is below. The result I'm getting is:

[image]

What I expected (and desire) is more like below (notice red lines on result):

[image]

For what it's worth, my end game is to auto rotate the image so the receipt is straight. If I'm taking the wrong path entirely, advise would be appreciated.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot


def detect_lines(img):

    temp = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
    lower = np.uint8([0, 160, 0])
    upper = np.uint8([255, 255, 255])
    white_mask = cv2.inRange(temp, lower, upper)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.blur(gray, (3, 3))

    canny_low = 100
    edges = cv2.Canny(white_mask, canny_low, canny_low * 3, apertureSize=5)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 10, 2, 80)

    result = img.copy()
    if lines is not None:
        for x in range(0, len(lines)):
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[x]:
                print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
                cv2.line(result, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    pyplot.subplot(141), pyplot.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Original Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([])

    pyplot.subplot(142), pyplot.imshow(white_mask, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Gray Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([])

    pyplot.subplot(143), pyplot.imshow(edges, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Edge Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([])

    pyplot.subplot(144), pyplot.imshow(result, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Result Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([])

    pyplot.show()
    return img


if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = cv2.imread('receipt.jpg')
    image = detect_lines(image)
    cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', image)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the original image?

Comment: Sure it's just a random image off Google.
https://thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/180503-ihop-n-word-receipt-embed.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&strip=all

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest start looking at different [Morphological Transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) which you can apply to your canny edge detection in order to improve the hough line transform.

This is not perfect but it's something to get you started:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot


def detect_lines(img):

    temp = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8) # < --- Added a kernel you can differ
    lower = np.uint8([0, 160, 0])
    upper = np.uint8([255, 255, 255])
    white_mask = cv2.inRange(temp, lower, upper)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.blur(gray, (3, 3))

    canny_low = 100
    edges = cv2.Canny(white_mask, canny_low, canny_low * 3, apertureSize=3)
    dilate = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=2) # < --- Added a dilate, check link I provided
    ero = cv2.erode(dilate, kernel, iterations=1) # < --- Added an erosion, check link I provided
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilate, 1, np.pi/180, 10, 2, 80)

    result = img.copy()
    if lines is not None:
        for x in range(0, len(lines)):
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[x]:
                print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
                cv2.line(result, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    pyplot.subplot(151), pyplot.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Original Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([])

    pyplot.subplot(152), pyplot.imshow(white_mask, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Mask Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([])

    pyplot.subplot(153), pyplot.imshow(edges, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Edge Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([])

    pyplot.subplot(154), pyplot.imshow(ero, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Dilate/Erosion Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([]) # <--- Added a display

    pyplot.subplot(155), pyplot.imshow(result, cmap='gray')
    pyplot.title('Result Image'), pyplot.xticks([]), pyplot.yticks([])

    pyplot.show()
    return result # <--- You want to return the result right?


if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = cv2.imread('receipt.jpg')
    image = detect_lines(image)
    cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', image)
```

[image]

Another approach could be looking into [Corner Detection](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_corner.html) and then drawing a line between the detected corners (I haven't tried this approach but it's just for inspiration :) ).